# Particles and Textures and Density

Tags: particles

**Goal**

Particles density produced by Texture Image Sequences such as black and white.

**Current Situation**

Unreliable Failed results.

**Question**

Below particles correspond to Black and White, if I take manual intervention by clicking say ramp on .... ramp off repeatedly, the usual incantations.  I have never achieved a successful render of an image sequence.  Single Image I can achieve as in the below pic.

Has anyone achieved reliable results with the above goal and if so how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (and I might not) and you want to control particle emission with an image sequence, then this isn't possible. Only the first image in an image sequence will be taken into account for particle density.

According to Brecht, one of the Blender developers [here](https://developer.blender.org/T28212):

> The problem here is a limitation of the particle system. The way it works is that a distribution of particles is generated once beforehand (to have an even distribution), and can't be dynamically changed.

Comment: If this is a quote, is there a date timestamp?

Comment: The date is shown at the link I provided. There were several newer links saying the same thing, but they were explained more briefly than this one.