# How to use image sequence to control particles?

Tags: particles

I have image sequence that I want to use to control particle spawn area.
Image sequence is black and white mask in nature. It depicts a moving disc:

[image: Image sequence applied as texture in the material node editor]

When I try to use the same sequence to control particle spawn with the "Density" controller, I get very wacky results. They seem fine in viewport as you will se in the gif below, but in render results are wrong.

[image: Viewport display, seems fine]

Render of the same scene, does not look like a viewport result

[image: Render result]

Here I made a gif of my process (20mb): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-GA9eF6biSXK4Nv2on2QecZgIRAdwrOS/view?usp=sharing

So how do I control particle spawn with the image sequence the right way?

Unfortunately blender can't pack image sequences in to file, so i put my blend file and image sequence here: (1.3mb total) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CcxzUDwEFGFghC-nYHWwr8zidshfLb7y?usp=sharing

Comment: is it necessary that it is an image sequence? Because what you show here you could easily recreate with a flag cylinder and animate that....

Comment: Yes, this scene is just a test for more complex effect where i would need to emit particles from black and white (mask in nature) image sequence. More to that, i want to to know why this relatively simple setup does not function. Is it a bug or what is the reason for it.
What is a flag cylinder by the way? Out of curiosity.

Comment: Sorry, that’s a typo. I meant flat cylinder 

Comment: Have you tried baking the particles?

Comment: Are you talking about "Cache" in particle tab? Yes, you can see it in the big 20 mb gif that i posted in the question. In fact baking them makes situation even worse, result may become even jankier.

Comment: @3dsinghvfx Do you think AN can handle this? Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky more than me :) I got particles emitted only from a one frame (tested with 2.79, 2.83, 2.93 and according to [this answer and its link to devs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43290/2214) (also seen as closed bug report with this topic in 2017) ... seems like limitation persists. So what you see in your preview is a pure love of God :)

So ... seems like the only one option to control animation with texture is to translate animation into a gradient image.

[image: text]

- To prevent release from black pixels I used image with transparency (PNGA). For some weird reason I had to set Alpha > None to let it work as intended.
- To get a bit of randomness of release apply a Noise filter on image

[image: text]

[image]

I know you said your example is just a prove of concept, but probably you would be able reuse for your needs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I will try this approach later. Do you think this situation we experience is a bug? For me it does not look like Blender working correctly here.

Comment: I found this issue on BugTracker - 2013, 2015, 2017 ... always closed as invalid report. For all years devs say it is a "current limitation". I can understand to this, but if so ... it should be simply restricted from User Interface to avoid confusion.

Comment: In the link I provided in my answer, there is mentioned this report https://developer.blender.org/T28212 explaining the "thing". Also mentioned pending patch ... but as you can see it was moved to TODO list already in 2011 :) So ... long run :) And since all community is waiting for Particle nodes I don't thing it would be tackled. Maybe you would be more lucky with Animation Nodes.

Comment: So I tried my best ... https://devtalk.blender.org/t/particles-animated-texture-fails-image-sequence-movie/17427